# Android SDK ADT installation issue

Tags: android, sdk, installation, adt

I'm using ubuntu 9.10 on my laptop its a separate partition i just installed the latest version of eclipse and installed the java sdk and adt. I'm pretty sure i did it correctly because it willlet me create new android projects but I have been trying to import an existing one and ive been getting the following errors.

```
Menu declare-styleable Menu not found in file /home/michael/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-7/data/res/values/attrs.xml
[2011-04-14 21:39:33 - Android Framework Parser] Menu declare-styleable MenuItem not found in file /home/michael/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-7/data/res/values/attrs.xml
[2011-04-14 21:39:33 - Android Framework Parser] Menu declare-styleable MenuGroup not found in file /home/michael/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-7/data/res/values/attrs.xml
```

I looked in the said path and there was no attrs.xml at first so I looked up the source for it and added it myself and still no success and yes I've done every simple solution possible aka "clean and re-add". Does anyone know where im going wrong?

Comment: I have same problem. Did you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the project, go to "Android Tools" > "Fix Project Properties"

Answer (score 0):

Check your SDK and update it. System image might not be installed